# How to create a counter for the user who invites friends on facebook?

Tags: facebook

I developed an application as a tab page. Users fill out a registration form ... Then I would implement that every registered user can invite their friends to put "I like" on my fan page, every 3 friends (among those invited) who click on "like" the user receives a gift.

How is possible to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

When a user registers in your app you could try:

Make a special link for that user, like, 'Share this link with your friends: 'http://MYAPP.COM?user=000000', like a certain URL for each user, so when someone likes the app using that URL, you know who's friend it is.

Comment: e come faccio a capire quando qualcuno clicca su "mi piace" della mia fan page senza utilizzare il plugin?

Comment: pagina: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235567/js-detect-when-user-clicks-the-facebook-like-button

nel facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/